# Is this proof on relation and equivalence classes correct?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, equivalence-relations

**Let $R$ be the relation on all real numbers defined by:
$$ \forall x,y \in \Bbb R , xRy \iff x-y \in \Bbb Z. $$
Is it true that for all $a \in \Bbb R$; there exists an irrational number $b$ so that $b \in [a]$ ?**

I think this is *FALSE*.
Why?

Let $a = 2$ and $b$ be an irrational number. 
Now, $[2] = \{ x \in \Bbb Z | x \}$ which is a set of all integers.
So $b \notin [2]$ because $b$ is irrational and all $[2]$ is a set of integers which are rational.

Is this proof logically correct? I just started learning about equivalence. Thanks :) !!

Comment: Relax. It's just fine.

Comment: Thanks im glad its correct ! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is basically correct.

Maybe you should just prove that $[2]$ is actually the set of all integers (it is). I think you know how to do this and you didn't write all passages here to not overextend the question. But if you don't know, don't hesitate to ask.